# Método 'pre' do Mongoose, retorna this como objeto vazio

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Tenho o seguinte modelo, a onde quando for cadastrar o usuário no mongodb
, quero que ele encripte o password usando `bcryptjs`, utilizando o método do mongoose `UserSchema.pre('save'...`

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (app) => {

const mongoose = app.config.banco;

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: false
    },

    criacao: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async (next) => {
    console.log(this);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = hash;
    next();
});

const user = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
return user;
}
```

onde tenho um arquivo no diretório controller para fazer esse cadastro

```
module.exports = (app) => {

return {
    async cadastra(req, res) {
        const User = app.models.Usuario;
        const user = await User.create(req.body);
        res.json(user);

 }

 }
```

só que o método do `bcryptjs` indica que a propriedade `this.password`
é `undefined` onde também coloquei um `console.log(this)` dentro do método `pre` para verificar oque retornava, onde está retornando objeto literal vazio `{}`

**Erro que retorna no console**

```
 {}
(node:7000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, number
    at _async (c:\node-api\api-registro\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at c:\node-api\api-registro\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:223:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude sua *arrow function* para uma função normal.

> Uma expressão *arrow function* possui uma sintaxe mais curta quando comparada a uma expressão de função (*function expression*) e não tem seu próprio `this`, `arguments`, `super` ou `new.target`. Estas expressões de funções são melhor aplicadas para funções que não sejam métodos, e elas não podem ser usadas como construtoras (*constructors*).

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    console.log(this);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = hash;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se o amigo resolveu o problema, mas caso não tenha resolvido, o problema está em

```
password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: false
    },
```

Ao invés de usar o `select: false`, use `select: true`

Exemplo:

```
password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: true
    },
```

Isto serve principalmente se estiver usando um código para atualizar e manter a encriptação, como no exemplo:

```
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(next) {
  const userUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
  userUpdate.password = await bcrypt.hash(userUpdate.password, 10);

  // console.log(userUpdate); // The document that `findOneAndUpdate()` will modify

  userUpdate.save();

  next();
});
```

Caso o password esteja como `select: false` o objeto no banco de dados não vai ser atualizado. Pelo menos foi assim que resolvi parte do meu problema.

Comment: Outro detalhe que esqueci de dizer:

Para evitar atualizar todos os campos sempre que for fazer update, evite utilizar o método http PUT, ao invés disso use o PATCH, pois ele possibilita atualizar cada campo independentemente, já o método PUT substitui todo o objeto.